# How replace numbers in a specific line

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I need to replace numbers only in a specific line in a multiple files with sed (or awk).

The numbers in the third line must be replaced with **{{ serial }}**

Example for a dns file under /etc/bind/master:

```
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     test.ex.it. host.test.it. (
                    2016060600         ; Serial
                         10800         ; Refresh
                          3600         ; Retry
```

Must Become:

```
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     test.ex.it. host.test.it. (
                    {{ serial }}       ; Serial
                         10800         ; Refresh
                          3600         ; Retry
```

I tried with sed sed

> ('s/[0-9]/{{ serial }}/g')

but couldn't get the numbers only in the third line.

How can i do that with "sed" or "awk" from the unix command line?

Thank you

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve this problem, also be more clear in your question(by adding more details in it).

Comment: Sorry, but other details how? the question seems very clear to me. I need to replace numbers with text enclosed in braces. What else do I have to say?

Comment: Like when and which kind of digits should be replaced? ++ please do add your efforts too.

Comment: I wrote it! The numbers in the third line (11111111 ;Serial) with the example of how it is and how it should be.

Added, hope its ok now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -E '3s,[0-9]+,{{ serial }},g' file
```

Output :

```
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     test.ex.it. host.test.it. (
                    {{ serial }}         ; Serial
                         10800         ; Refresh
                          3600         ; Retry
```

To replace file :

```
sed -iE '3s,[0-9]+,{{ serial }},g' file
```

MacOS

```
sed -i '' E '3s,[0-9]+,{{ serial }},g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v line="3" 'FNR==line{gsub(/[0-9]+/,"{{ serial }}")} 1'  Input_file
```

Where `line` is variable to have line where you want to make changes to all digits.

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp && mv temp Input_file` in above command like as follows(please run it once you are ok with above command's output only).

```
awk -v line="3" 'FNR==line{gsub(/[0-9]+/,"{{ serial }}")} 1'  Input_file > temp && mv Input_file
```

PS: BTW are you trying to write jinja logic of python looks like that(either Ansible or Django's templates :) just mentioning)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Yes it's for ansible, but in this case i need to set {{ serial }} variable for like 120 files. for this I have to do this manual modification to all the files. :)

Comment: @Luca, if file names are similar for example `.txt` then you could pass `awk.........     *.txt` in one code but check it better 1 by 1. This command would have worked for you for a single file, let me know?

Comment: it worked too. But i have no file extension. The file are under /etc/bind/master, so are all file of domain zone

Comment: @Luca, you could still run this command only for files by using `find -type f .....awk ...` command for sure we may need to fine tune it more, let me check if I can do it. This command is more robust in terms of you need not to hard code any line number in it, you can simply change variable value and it will work.